Fix python flask routing 404 error: firebase
I'm currently developing a basic web platform using javascript, html, and python flask. I'm using firebase for hosting. I have a javascript function looking something like this:
function giveData() {
    const data = {
        variable1: testName,
        variable2: timeUntil,
        variable3: timeCommit,
        variable4: additionalInfo
    };
    console.log("Sending data to server:", data);
    fetch('/mywebsite/update_data', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
}

and have some more code structured to receive and display the response. In my python, I have something like this:
@app.route('/mywebsite/update_data', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def update_data():
    global actualData  # Declare actualData as global
    actualData = request.json
    
    topics_list = getTopics(actualData['variable1'], actualData['variable2'], actualData['variable3'], actualData['variable4'])
    return jsonify({'topics_list': topics_list})

where "mywebsite" is the project's website I have it hosted on firebase. However, when I try to run the code, the giveData() function returns the following errors:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" from "/mywebsite/update_data:1"

and

"SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON" from script.js/144.

I think the two errors are really the same problem, which is that the fetch command can't find the file and function from python. I have all the files in my public directory, which is the one I specified for hosting on Firebase. I've tried a lot of different paths in the fetch statement, but I can't seem to get anything to work. Also, for some reason, my partner ran it from VSCODE locally using the port 127.0.0.1:5000, and it worked there. It seems to be some issue on my end, or with the hosting.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

How are you hosting your Flask app? You can deploy it to Cloud Functions but you'd also need to invoke the HTTP function using the correct URL and not a relative one like /mywebsite/update_data

Thanks! A couple questions, though: I was looking at the documentation, and the examples didn't seem to use Flask. Would I still need flask for my app if I used Cloud Functions? Also, I started the cloud functions process, and ran functions init, which seemed to work fine. However, I've selected the "public" directory for my site, and this created a new subfolder in the project. Should I add the "functions" subfolder inside of "public", or will it run fine without this?

Also, I think I'd have to pay to host on firebase. Is there a free alternative?
